# How to fix "Detected out of bounds geographic extent"

Tags: qgis, postgis, tilemill

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem. 
i want to make a map with `TileMill v.01`, when i try to add layer using shapefile (i use `QGIS` to edit `*.shp` file) or postGIS i always get error message : 
 `Detected out of bounds geographic extent (289148.0964570158,9020963.6199987,180,85.051) for layer 'badung'. Please ensure that the SRS for this layer is correct. Its native extent is '289148.0964570158,9020963.6199987,307432.8551368474,9088475.5022231'`


i think if i change the `geom` property in postGIS using this WGS84 (4326) will fix this problem, apparently not. **could someone give me the way to fix this problem ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the CRS property does **NOT** change the coordinates.

Inside QGIS, you have to use `Save As ...` to another file name and CRS EPSG:4326.

Then the coordinates will be inside the bounds of +/- 180/90°.

Comment: i still dont know what should i do. could you give me an example or something else to fix this problem?.

Comment: The shapefile you want to add is in a local projection. If you load it into QGIS, the CRS should be detected automatically. Then save the layer under a diffeent name, selecting EPSG:4326 as CRS, and use that for tilemill.